# Unable to Start Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am using Neo4j 3.2.2 on Linux with Java 1.8 (open JDK). When I try to start neo4j using "systemctl start neo4j" - executing this doesn't give me any output. When I execute "systemctl status neo4j" I see that it has failed to start the database. [Error when i check the status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH8SG.png)

When I check journalctl, this is what I see[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6De3.png)

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: it seems that you have a bad jvm configuration (specially with the G1 GC). Can you share with us your `neo4j.cong` file ?

Comment: Indeed, the ^M in the error messages indicates that you moved your configuration from another OS (Windows ?) incorrectly ...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help and precise comment from Tom Geudens. Your comment helped me. I was use Filezilla to move files (specifically, the conf file) between windows and Linux. Once, I edited and saved the file (vi editor) within the Linux environment, everything was up.